# how hilt gernerated file works in android?

Tags: android, dagger-hilt

Studying with Hilt, I got some question.
Hilt DI library is based on code generation.
So I can find the generated files in app/build/generated/source/kapt/debug.
But I want to know how this files is working.
As I understand, are this files swapped at compile time by compiler?

Comment: Check out here - https://dagger.dev/hilt/